# Why do we "swap out" the variable of interest in an integral with some other variable?

Tags: probability, integration

I have the following question: **Why do we "swap out" the variable of interest in an integral with some other variable?**

For example, in the following integral:

[image]

The integral is set up in terms of a variable "Y". However, when the integral is actually written - "Y" is replaced with a new variable "Z" (e.g. dz).

**My Question:** Does anyone know why this happens? Why is it necessary to do this? Or is this just "mathematical tradition"?

Thanks!

**References:**

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tweedie_distribution

Comment: $Y$ is a "random variable" - that's a technical term. $z$ is just the variable of integration. These are different concepts.

Comment: @ ancient mathematician : thank you for your reply! Just a question: is my understanding correct? in the above integral - are "z" and "Y" interchangeable? Thank you!

Comment: I've already said they are different concepts so of course they are not interchangeable. You've really got to go back to the definition of "random variable" and of "probability distribution".

Comment: Cross-posted: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/552647/relationship-between-random-variable-and-variable-of-integration